# What is the name for $(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 +...)/(a + b + c +...)$?

Tags: terminology, gm.general-mathematics, norms

That is, the sum of squares of some numbers divided by the sum of the numbers. The term "anti-harmonic mean" has been coined for this quantity. I'm hoping there is a better name.

Comment: Do you like "contraharmonic mean" better? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraharmonic_mean for details and references.

Comment: Yes, I do. At least it has some history. Thanks!

Comment: Five people vote to close a question, and not one of them leaves a comment indicating a reason. This leaves me with no idea as to what could be the objection to this question. 

Comment: +1 on Gerry Myerson's comment. But seeing that Doug Chatham has already provided what is possibly a satisfactory answer in the comments above, I won't vote to re-open. 

Comment: @Willie Wong, I agree. I am, however, sorely tempted to bring it up in meta. 